# Convert Mongo query to Mgo query

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to retrieve all id and field2 from mongo document, if field1 equals some value and field2 exists.

Example:
Mongo Document:

```
{

       "id": "id1"
       "field1": "val1"
       "field2": "val2"
       "field3": "val3"
}

{

      "id": "id2"
      "field1": "val4"
      "field3": "val5"
}
```

Result

```
{

    "id" : "id1"
    "field2": "val2"
}
```

I figured out mongodb query that works:

```
dbname.find( { $and: [ { "field1": "val1" }, { "field2": { $exists: true } } ] } , {"id":1, "field2":1})
```

But I want to call this query in Go using Mgo package. I'm unable to convert make this mongo query call using Mgo. I tried a few ways but they don't seem to be working. Can anyone help me out here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical AND is the default, so you can generously leave that out:

```
dbname.find({"field1": "val1", "field2": {$exists: true}, {"id": 1, "field2": 1})
```

In `mgo`:

In general just use a [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M) map value for each brackets (where keys must be `string` values). For projection use [`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Select).

```
sess := ... // Acquire an mgo session

c := sess.DB("dbname").C("collname") // Use your db name and collection name

var docs []bson.M
err := c.Find(bson.M{
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": bson.M{"$exists": true},
}).Select(bson.M{"id": 1, "field2": 1}).All(&docs)

if err != nil {
    // Handle err
    log.Printf("Query error: "%v", err)
    return
}

// Process results
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me convert this MongoDB query to mgo, please? Here db.users.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: "users",
          startWith: "$user_parentid",
          connectFromField: "user_parentid",
          connectToField: "_id",
          as: "hierarchy"
      }
   },
  { 
      $match: { 
          $or: [ 
             { "hierarchy._id":  "BOMON_VIENTHONG" },
             { _id: "BOMON_VIENTHONG" }
          ]
      } 
  }
] 
).forEach( doc => db.users.deleteOne( { _id: doc._id } ) )